# Diff, show modified line from right file only

Tags: shell-script, sed, awk, diff

I have file `a` and `b` and I would like to output lines of `b` that changed since it was cloned from `a`. Just the modified lines, no surrounding context, no diff offset marks.

How can I do that using shell scripting? (No Python/Perl/PHP/...)

Sed and awk are acceptable solutions.

For now, what I am doing is diff -y with --suppress-common-lines and sed using regex backreferences to just fetch the right part after the whitespace. There must be a better way?

Using perl (which is forbidden), I´d do something like this:

```
diff -y --suppress-common-lines -W $COLUMNS Eclipse_Preferences_Export_*.epf | perl -pe 's/.*\t|\t(.*)$/\1/g'
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

With GNU *diffutils* package's `diff` this will output only lines from file b which either were modified or newly inserted:

```
diff --unchanged-line-format= --old-line-format= --new-line-format='%L' a b
```

Comment: Awesome. Shame the info is buried in the Texinfo and no hint is provided in the man page I was reading..

Answer (score 6):

You have to add one more option :

```
grep -vf file1 file2
```

Comment: While this doesn't require the lines to be sorted, I think grep uses a lot more memory and will crash for large files.

Comment: doesn't work if lines are duplicated either

Comment: incorrect answer, the correct use of grep is this: grep -vxF -f file1 file2

Answer (score 4):

```
awk 'FNR==NR{old[$0];next};!($0 in old)' old.txt new.txt
```