# Show only changed lines without syntax with git diff

Tags: text-processing, git, diff

I have a list of usernames that are in a text file.  I update this file and commit it.  I am looking for a way to get a list of the changes since the last commit.

I do not want any diff formatting at all, I just want to get an output that has usernames one per line (as they are added to each commit) since the last commit.

I can't find a setting that will remove all the git diff syntax from the output so it's purely a list new lines added only.

## Example

Original file:

```
user1
user2
user3
```

I then add

```
user4
user5
```

Then commit.

I want to be able to do a git diff and see only:

```
user4
user5
```

Comment: [This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/56625/86440) shows how to do this with GNU `diff`, but `git diff` doesn’t support the relevant options.

Answer (score 6):

You could grep the diff output combining lookahead/lookbehind:

```
git diff --unified=0 | grep -Po '(?<=^\+)(?!\+\+).*'
```

- `(?<=^\+)` is a positive lookbehind for line starting with `+`
- `(?!\+\+)` is a negative lookahead to prevent matching files headers starting with `+++ a/path/to/file`.

The `--unified=0` git option is just there to reduce the numbers of line to filter removing diff context, it is optional though.

There is probably better, I'm not fluent in PCRE.

Answer (score 3):

Borrowing `--unified=0` from kaiko answer I came to:

```
git diff HEAD^ HEAD --unified=0 | tail +6 | sed -e 's/^\+//'
```

Comment: Should't it be `-6`. `+6` gives: `tail: cannot open '+6' for reading: No such file or directory`.

Comment: @pevik Depends on your `tail` flavor... If `+6` is not ok, try `--lines=+6` but look at the specific manual of your tail command. `-6` and `+6` have a different meaning, `-6` would mean last 6 lines (because tail "starts" from the end) where `+6` means "output everything from line 6 to end".

Comment: You have POSIX definition of `tail` at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tail.html#tag_20_125 . In theory the correct writing should be `-n +6`.

Comment: Sure, `-n +6` works for various implementations (coreutils, busybox). But plain `+6` works on busybox, but not on coreutils implementation.